# ALL clause in different SQL platforms

Tags: mysql, sql, database, postgresql

I am doing some interview practice and I ran into this interesting SQL problem.

Given a table with schema world(name, continent, area, population, gdp) Find the largest country (by area) in each continent, show the continent, the name and the area.

A possible solution would be:

```
SELECT continent, name, area
FROM world x  
WHERE area >= ALL (
    SELECT area FROM world y  
    WHERE y.continent=x.continent)
```

I don't really understand how the ALL keyword works, so I don't know how this query actually solves the problem. Also, does the use of ALL differ between SQL platforms?

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/all-subqueries.html

Answer (score 1):

As for your question - as far as I've understood, your SQL will be simple:

```
SELECT 
  MAX(area) AS max_area, 
  continent,
  name
GROUP BY
  continent,
  name
```

As for `ALL` normally, it works as it's quite as it should be from `ALL` meaning: i.e. some value fits given condition (in your case, "greater or equal to") against **all** values in subquery.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this won't answer your question but will help you with understanding MySQL `ALL`

`ALL` keyword returns the data if a given row in outer query satisfies the condition for all the row values returned by the sub-query :

Here is an example :

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM t1;
+------+
| i    |
+------+
|    1 |
|    2 |
|    3 |
|    4 |
|    5 |
+------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT * FROM t2;
+------+
| j    |
+------+
|    2 |
|    4 |
|    6 |
+------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)


mysql> SELECT * FROM t1 WHERE i = ALL (SELECT j FROM t2);
Empty set (0.00 sec)
```

Here empty set is returned because MySQL compares a given value from t1 table with all the values in table t2. If a value from t1 is equal to all the values returned by sub-query then it will show it as output.

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM t1 WHERE i <> ALL (SELECT j FROM t2);
+------+
| i    |
+------+
|    1 |
|    3 |
|    5 |
+------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Here it show all those values from t1 table which are not at all equal to the values returned by the sub-query.

Also, `<>ALL` is functionally equivalent to `NOT IN`
and `=ANY` is functionally equivalent to `IN`

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM t1 WHERE i = ALL (SELECT j FROM t2 WHERE j = 2);
+------+
| i    |
+------+
|    2 |
+------+
1 row in set (0.12 sec)
```

Here it returns 2 as output because 2(from table t1) matches with the only output generated by the sub-query.

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT x.continent, x.name, x.area
FROM world x,
     (SELECT continent, MAX(area)
      FROM world x 
      GROUP BY continent) max_res
WHERE x.area=max_res.area
      AND x.continent=max_res.continent
```

Comment: @AlmaDo sorry corrected a bit the query. In the subquery we calculate the biggst area for each continent. After that we get all countries for each continent with the area.

Comment: I see the meaning - but - why? I mean, simple `GROUP BY`, it seems, will fit the question (oh, that dv wasn't mine)

Comment: @AlmaDo *show the continent, the name and the area.* we have to show name of the country. And process the case when there are 2 max area countries.

Comment: So.. group by two columns? (sorry if it seems stupid from my side, but I really can't see why single query with groping by two column won't fit OP question)

Comment: @AlmaDo imagine there are 2 countries with the same area (=max(area))

Comment: But we want one of them. You're right, it's a "corner case", but I think since OP didn't specified that that should be - any country will be good. Ok, I agree with - where could be difference (in common case)